# How use dir() function to see inside scrapy module

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

So i try see inside the `scrapy` module

`import scrapy` is a module right, or im wrong?

```
>>>dir(scrapy)
```

> NameError: name 'scrapy' is not defined

Im complete newb in python and just try understand how works.

How can i see inside modules like documentation examples

```
>>> dir(sys)  
['__displayhook__', '__doc__', '__excepthook__', '__loader__', '__name__',
 '__package__', '__stderr__', '__stdin__', '__stdout__',
 '_clear_type_cache', '_current_frames', '_debugmallocstats', '_getframe',
 '_home', '_mercurial', '_xoptions', 'abiflags', 'api_version', 'argv',
 'base_exec_prefix', 'base_prefix', 'builtin_module_names', 'byteorder',
 'call_tracing', 'callstats', 'copyright', 'displayhook',
 'dont_write_bytecode', 'exc_info', 'excepthook', 'exec_prefix',
 'executable', 'exit', 'flags', 'float_info', 'float_repr_style',
 'getcheckinterval', 'getdefaultencoding', 'getdlopenflags',
 'getfilesystemencoding', 'getobjects', 'getprofile', 'getrecursionlimit',
 'getrefcount', 'getsizeof', 'getswitchinterval', 'gettotalrefcount',
 'gettrace', 'hash_info', 'hexversion', 'implementation', 'int_info',
 'intern', 'maxsize', 'maxunicode', 'meta_path', 'modules', 'path',
 'path_hooks', 'path_importer_cache', 'platform', 'prefix', 'ps1',
 'setcheckinterval', 'setdlopenflags', 'setprofile', 'setrecursionlimit',
 'setswitchinterval', 'settrace', 'stderr', 'stdin', 'stdout',
 'thread_info', 'version', 'version_info', 'warnoptions']
```

Comment: You didn't import scrapy.

Comment: Negative are welcome, any tip to made this question better?

Comment: @user2357112 what about thats examples with `import scrapy` https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this from your python interpreter:

```
In [1]: import scrapy

In [2]: dir(scrapy)
Out[2]: 
['Field',
 'FormRequest',
 'Item',
 'Request',
 'Selector',
 'Spider',
 '__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 '_txv',
 'exceptions',
 'http',
 'item',
 'link',
 'selector',
 'signals',
 'spiders',
 'twisted_version',
 'utils',
 'version_info']
```

This worked for me in both Python 2 and 3. I have also confirmed that it works in both iPython and the standard interpreter. If it does not work for you even with the import, your environment may have gotten messed up in some way, and we can troubleshoot further.

> `import scrapy` is a module right, or im wrong?

In this case `scrapy` is a module, and `import scrapy` is the syntax for making that module available in whatever context you are invoking the import from. [This section of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/modules.html) has information on modules and importing them.

Comment: Tks for atention man, for real, im extreme new in python, how acess interpreter, is like `$python` in command line so, get me to `>>>` prompt python?

Comment: @MagicHat yes, that should work. Are you able to access the interpreter?

Comment: `>>> import scrapy`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'` What can it be?

Comment: Ah, OK. You will first need to do `$ pip install scrapy` before entering the interpreter (`$` representing that you are at a command prompt for you terminal). Here is some info on `pip`: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/venv.html#managing-packages-with-pip

Comment: I have scrapy installed, but recently i change version python after that, from 2.7 to 3, can be that?

Comment: Yes, if you previously installed scrapy for Python 2, you will need to do so again for Python 3 to make it available in a Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!